# Purescript Halogen Component, Input vs State

Tags: purescript, halogen

I want to make a Halogen Component where the component's input differs from its state. According to the guide for Halogen (https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/master/docs/5%20-%20Parent%20and%20child%20components.md#input-values) this should be possible. I changed the example from the guide as follows

```
import Prelude
import Data.Int (decimal, toStringAs)
import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML as HH
import Halogen.HTML.Events as HHE

type Input = Int

type State = String

data Query a = HandleInput Input a

component :: forall m. H.Component HH.HTML Query Input Void m
component =
  H.component
    { initialState: id
    , render
    , eval
    , receiver: HHE.input HandleInput
    }
  where

  render :: State -> H.ComponentHTML Query
  render state =
    HH.div_
      [ HH.text "My input value is:"
      , HH.strong_ [ HH.text (show state) ]
      ]

  eval :: Query ~> H.ComponentDSL State Query Void m
  eval = case _ of
    HandleInput n next -> do
      oldN <- H.get
      when (oldN /= (toStringAs decimal n)) $ H.put $ toStringAs decimal n
      pure next
```

But then I get a compile error at the line with `, receiver: HHE.input HandleInput`

```
Could not match type

  String

with type

  Int
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initialState` is computed using the input value, and in the code you pasted it's implemented as `id`, so it's trying to force the input and state types to match.

Answer (score 0):

Changed line `{ initialState: id` in `{ initialState: const initialState` and added after `where` the following lines

```
initialState :: State
initialState = ""
```